# Perl - Check if the current time between 9PM and 6AM

Tags: perl, time

I'm looking for the best way to determine whether the current time is between 9PM and 6AM, and perform the relevant action, depending on the boolean.

I'm not entirely sure on the best way of doing this though... I'm thinking I could maybe use epoch time (Time::Local) to get the time as it was at 9PM last night, and the time that it will be at 6AM the following day - but is this the best way of doing it or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Try thinking of your problem in reverse: if the current time, expressed in 24-hour format, is after 06:00 and before 21:00, then the condition is false. So you need only one piece of information: the current hour, in 24-hour format.

Comment: @IMSoP of course - that makes a lot more sense. Thank you IMSoP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all that is necessary

```
my $hour = (localtime)[2];
if ( $hour >= 21 or $hour < 6 ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin - much better than what I had planned with epoch... (you know you've been looking at the code too long when you are overcomplicating it!) Thank you again. +1

Comment: What if the current hour is say 14 and the range is 9 till 13?